# Should I seek employment 'from' a company or 'at' a company?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

I'm having a hard time distinguishing between the two words. I'm unsure of seeking employment "from" or seeking employment "at" a company.

The particular sentence I have in mind is this "[some context]...gain as much experience as possible before seeking employment *from/at* your company."

Comment: or even "*with* a company".  You do not give enough information.  "At" implies a specific location; whereas "from" or "with" need not have that implication. For example, if you are working from home, or travelling as a salesman, etc. you may not be working *at* the company, but you will be working *for* them

Comment: Well, the particular sentence is this "[some context]...gain as much experience as possible before seeking employment from/at your company."

Comment: I would use "*with*", as suggested in the answer from @k1eran.

Comment: In this specific example, I would probably say "seeking a position at your company".

Answer (score 2):

I think **employment with** is more idiomatic and is backed up by a google Ngram search.

[image: NGRAM]

Answer (score 2):

If it's for a cover letter, and you're seeking a particular position, state the position and how much you, with your experience, skills, etc., would contribute to the position and the company:

"...before seeking the position of [insert name of position] with [insert name of company.]"

If you do a simple search online there are lots of great, free examples of cover letters and letters of interest that could even be specific to your particular field. Most local libraries have resume-building workshops too.

To answer your question specifically, I would choose "with" because it implies 1) that you are a good match for that company and its mission (whereas "at" or "in" implies a vertical relationship) and 2) you are a "team player/investor" who contributes your own wealth of knowledge, energy, and labor to the shared goal of the company's success.

Comment: Yes, agree in particular on last paragraph. **With** implies a more equal (perhaps professional-level job) relationship between the employee & employer

Answer (score 1):

Rather than "with", as suggested in the answer from @k1eran, I would prefer "**in** the company" because you are looking for a position in the company.

Comment: "employment *in* the company" sounds strange to my (British) ears.

Comment: @TrevorD - [example](http://www.ons.gov.uk/employmentandlabourmarket/peopleinwork/employmentandemployeetypes/articles/qualificationsandlabourmarketparticipationinenglandandwales/2014-06-18) from the UK 'Office for National Statistics': *This could be partly because apprenticeships are job-related schemes which may often lead to employment in the company where the individuals are trained*.

Comment: Noted! ... ... ...